# Rails: Removing HTML codes from string?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tags, meta-tags

I'm getting something like this: `&lt;h1&gt;` in inspect element, and I want to be able to remove all tags like this. I'm trying to have a clean meta tag description, but because I'm using description from rich text editor, those ampersand symbols are showing up.

I'm not sure what these are called?

They're not `<h1>Title</h1>` tags where I tried `strip_tags(@notes)`, and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

These are called htmlentities. You had the right idea, to strip tags, but this function only works when they are decoded. It might be that you use html_safe at the form where they are typed in in the first place.

Install the HTMLentities gem (https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities). Then decode your tags and then strip tags. You can encapsulate the methods, like `strip_tags(coder.decode(@notes))`.

But make sure you properly installed HTMLentities like it is described in the gem's readme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}

// Example
alert(decodeHtml('Hello &lt;strong&gt;world&lt;/strong&gt;!Hello <strong>world</strong>!'))
```

Comment: Will this work for more complex phrases? Like `Hello <strong>world</strong>!`

Comment: Yes - I added an example

Comment: This is good if I wanted to strip certain tags, but in my case, I wanted to strip all

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. I read it wrong. I thought this code only stripped the html entity, I provided in the question, but I see it now! Thanks!

Comment: So this just decodes the HTMLentities, and then you can apply strip_tags to this?

Comment: @hellomello So did it work for you? Or do you need any more help?

Comment: This is in javascript right? I'm trying to do this in rails application, where this is being displayed as a meta tag so websites like Facebook can scrape the correct description of the page without having html tags or entities

Comment: so should i delete the answer?

Comment: Sure, its up to you. It may be helpful for someone else who's looking for something like this